# if $f(z)=z\operatorname{Im}z$, what are the singular points?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)=z\operatorname{Im}z$, what are the singular points?

I know that $f'(z)$ exists only in $z=0$ but I think it has no singular points because if I take any ball around $z\neq0$ then $f$ is not analytic so it doesn’t have singular points.

Comment: Yes, according to the usual definition a singular point of $f$  is a boundary point of the region $D$ where $f$ is analytic.  Here  $D$ is empty, so there are no singular points.